# A subspace of a mapping space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

We have a set

$$ M=\{f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\mid f(1)>0\}\;.$$

I have never encountered this kind of set before.

I assume it is correct to say that $M$ is a subspace of a mapping space?

That this subspace is open if it maps to open sets like in this
case and that it is closed if it maps to closed sets?

And that its interior is $(0,\infty)$ and its closure $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: I would use the term "function space," but yes, the "points" in a vector space may very well be functions. These objects are fundamental in the study of functional analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$
X=\{f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \}
$$

Then $X$ is a function space, as mentioned in the comments. Note that $M \subset X$. Also note that $M$ is a function space in its own right.

What would it mean to call a subset of $X$ open? Well, there's a field of math called topology that studies how one would go about defining this. But if you haven't specified a "topology" on your space, you can't use the word "open." It's undefined.

On the reals, there is a standard topology that has to do with intervals. The meaning of "open" is normally just clear by context. It means a union of intervals of the form $(a,b)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. On the other hand, $X$ (and $M$ for that matter) don't have an obvious topology. So it isn't clear from context.

Also, how could $(0,\infty)$ be the interior of $M$? It isn't even a subset of $M$. It's in the wrong space.

Comment: I have just started to study topology and especially these function spaces i havent seen before. I think I understand what you mean. So somehow you have to specify a topology for these functions? Could you do something like this: You specify the open sets in the topology on $X$ to be the functions that maps to open sets in the reals. Then $M$ is open in the subspace topology because $M \cap U$ for a $U \in \tau_x$ Or is this wrong too?

Comment: Well, keep in mind $M$ and $X$, as defined here, are filled with nasty, badly discontinuous functions. Defining a useful topology on $X$ is hard. Your attempt is a good instinct. Using what you know about open sets in the reals to build other topologies is a good approach. But your building the wrong kind of set. You want a criteria that applies to an entire subset $U\subset X$. Imagine something like "$U$ is open if for every $f\in U$, something is true about $f$.